# Travis pypi package version

Tags: python, travis-ci, pypi

I've setted up travis.ci to automatically deploy to pypi a package when a push to master is tagged.

The problem is that in my `setup.py` I've to specify the package version, and sometimes I forget that resulting in a non deployed package (or does Pypi overwrites the old one?)

Nevertheless, Is there a way to match the package version on pypi as the tag that is assigned to the commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already done it in one of my projects.

**[EDIT N°2]** I wrote a little tutorial you can find here: https://github.com/73VW/Publishing-to-PyPI-with-pbr-and-Travis

## V1. Using PBR

You can find it [here on Github](https://github.com/73VW/AutomaBot).

What Travis basically does is the following:

- Check if commit has a tag
- If so, check the format with a regex (`/(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$/`)
- If the tag is something like `1.0.0` it uses it for pypi version.

  <s>You can still transform the regex to also match tags like `v1.0.0`. Use something like `/v?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$/`</s>

  **[EDIT N°3] This was completely wrong, PBR can't define version if the tag doesn't match what is described here https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/3.1.0/semver.html.**

I use [PBR](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/) to do this.

> A library for managing setuptools packaging needs in a consistent manner.

Check the following files in my repository:

- [.travis.yml](https://github.com/73VW/AutomaBot/blob/master/.travis.yml)
- [setup.py](https://github.com/73VW/AutomaBot/blob/master/setup.py)
- [setup.cfg](https://github.com/73VW/AutomaBot/blob/master/setup.cfg)

If you still have troubles, feel free to tag me (@73VW) on github or ask directly here.

Have a nice day.

### [EDIT]

## V2. Using sed

In git you can get the last tag with the following command `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`

Thereby, if your setup is something like the following:

```py
from setuptools import setup
...

setup(
    ...
    version='NEWVERSIONHERE',
    ...
)
```

You could use a shell script to replace `NEWVERSIONHERE` by your tag version.

I tried the following (locally, not on Travis) and it works.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -xe
TAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)

sed -i "s/NEWVERSIONHERE/${TAG}/g" setup.py
```

The `-i` flag is used to find and replace in place. Thereby it changes in the file you have specified.

Simply put this code in a shell script, **don't forget to `chmod` it in order to be able to run it**, and run it from Travis.

Example `.travis.yml` file:

```
dist: trusty
sudo: required

language: python
python: 3.6

cache: apt

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - chmod 777 YOURSCRIPT.sh

script:
  - your tests here
  - ./YOURSCRIPT.sh

deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: pypi
  distributions: sdist bdist_wheel
  on:
    tags: true
    branch:
      - master
      - /(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$/
  user: YOUR PYPI USERNAME
  password:
  secure: YOUR PYPI ENCODED PASSWORD
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a solution to let travis set up the version as per the tag? it builds the tag but then how can i tell travis to add the version as the one in the git? do I really need to use extrapackages for this trival, mandatory, task?

Comment: I am not sure to really understand your questions correctly. English is not my native language. 
As far as my project is concerned, travis deploys to pypi when it encounters tags matching the regex. 
From then, pbr does everything else. It takes the tag and assigns it as package version.
I don't know any other way but there might be. You could get the tag from git, and then "sed" it into your setup file or something like that.
Tell me if I don't answer your questions.

Comment: That's perfectly clear, I was asking if trevis can do that for me without the need of installing the PBR.

Comment: Okay, here I am reassured haha. 

I can't tell you if Travis can do that without PBR but it was the only way **I found** and **I know** to do it easily. There might other ways.

Comment: @EsseTi I updated my answer with another way of doing it. Hope this helps! If this is the case, please accept my answer. Have a nice day.